# Hamiltonian path using iGraph

Tags: igraph

I started evaluating igraph library and its functionality.
I need to calculate hamiltonian path of a graph generated by igraph_de_bruijn() function.
Is there any ready made function in igraph library for that? I don't want to implement it from scratch.
An example in C would be perfect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Hamiltonian path problem can be cast as a subgraph isomorphism problem, for which igraph has several functions.   Construct a 1D lattice graph (a "line") with the same number of vertices as your graph, then search for this pattern using subisomorphism functions.

Here's an example using the [Mathematica interface](https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM).

```
hamiltonianPath[g_] := 
 Values@First@IGLADGetSubisomorphism[
    GridGraph[{VertexCount[g]}],  (* <- this is just a 1D lattice, like O-O-O-O *)
    g                             (* <- this is the graph we want to match *)
 ]
```

Let's try a dodecahedral graph:

```
g = PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "SkeletonGraph"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here's the order the vertices need to be visited in:

```
path = hamiltonianPath[g]

(* {1, 16, 7, 3, 14, 9, 17, 19, 5, 11, 12, 8, 4, 20, 6, 2, 13, 18, 10, 15} *)
```

Let's visualize it:

```
HighlightGraph[g, PathGraph[path], GraphHighlightStyle -> "Thick"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I use Mathematica only for illustration.  The procedure is identical when using the C interface.

When you do this [from C](http://igraph.org/c/doc/), you can use `igraph_subisomorphic_lad` to find a *single* subisomorphism (see the `map` argument).  Use `igraph_ring` to create the pattern (`circular=false` for Hamiltonian path, `circular=true` for Hamiltonian cycle).  If you want the dodecahedron for a test case, you can get it with `igraph_famous`.

Answer (score 0):

I am looked on the Szabolcs' answer and try to find hamiltonian path as a subgraph isomorphism problem:

```
library(igraph)

n = 8
m <- t(matrix(c(
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,
3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
5,0,0,5,1,0,0,0,
0,0,6,0,0,7,1,0,
0,6,2,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
7,4,0,0,8,0,0,3,
0,3,0,0,0,9,0,0),ncol=n))

g1 <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(m, weighted=TRUE, mode="directed")
V(g1)$name <-  letters[1:n]
pattern <- make_lattice(length = n, dim = 1)
```

In my example, a number paths were found, I took the first:

```
path <- unlist(subgraph_isomorphisms(pattern, as.undirected(g1, mode = "each"), method = "vf2")[1])
path
#a b e c d f h g 
#1 2 5 3 4 6 8 7
```